# How to get the object key when using value in angularFire

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have below code to query the index from `users node` then pass the index to `todos node` to get the data I want but it only `watching` when a child is added so when a child is removed in the index it doesn't update the view.

I have no idea how to get the object key if I use `value` in the index node.
Any idea? or any better way to query mastered data using angularFire?

```
FirebaseRef.$child(user.uid).$on('child_added', function(a) {
 FirebaseRef.$child('todos/' + a.snapshot.name).$on('value', function(b) {
   $scope.todoList[a.snapshot.name] = b.snapshot;
 });
});
```

Comment: What is FirebaseRef? A Firebase instance or a $firebase/angularFire object? If it's a Firebase object, use .child instead of .$child. Assuming it's a $firebase instance, then it already contains all the contents of todos/. What is the use case we're trying to solve here? It looks like this could be resolved in a simpler manner.

Answer (score 0):

try the following (not tested).

```
FirebaseRef.$child(user.uid).$on('child_added', function(a) {
 FirebaseRef.$child('todos/' + a.name()).$on('value', function(b) {
   $scope.todoList[a.name()] = b.snapshot;
 });
});
```

You shouldn't need 'snapshot' in your reference eg a.snapshot.name, you should just reference the object returned in your callback function

Comment: AngularFire doesn't return the methods like pure firebase js api. It returns a list of objects so I cannot use `.name()` `.val()` etc when in angularFire